# Does SVN export always export everything or just new things?

Tags: svn

Say in my repository I add a file or make a change and commit that.  Another client who also has the source previously exported to them exports again.  Will they get the entire source or only the new stuff added?  If not what about checkout?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Checkout and Export are meant to retrieve all comitted files - Checkout creates a working copy whereas Export just gives you the files with no SVN attributes, and you cannot commit back.

If you wish to just get the latest changes, use Update after an initial Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Export and checkout may not be used as synonyms in relation with subversion.

```
svn checkout URL
```

creates a *working copy* from your source code repository.

```
svn export URL
```

creates a copy of your source code repository, *omitting* all versioning information as pointed out by @RedFilter. You won't be able to accomplish any versioning task with this copy.

Answer (score 0):

Export will work from the path you specify downwards, it will get that specific repository contents with no SVN support (no track of changes, commit, updates, etc.).

Checkout, on the other hand will get contents from the server specified, again from the path you tell it downwards, but will keep SVN metadata, so commits, updates will be possible.